# How to take still images in python? (Other than opencv CaptureVideo)

Tags: python, image-processing

I would like to take pictures using the USB webcam. When I use the VideoCapture method of OpenCV, it actually gives frames from the video. In most cases, still images cover more area than the video. Therefore, I am looking for a way to take pictures using the webcam which cover more of the available camera FOV.